# Using superscripts in C++Builder

Tags: text, c++builder

C++Builder 10.4.2

Putting text into a label with Tahoma font, I use `"lbf/in" + AnsiString((wchar_t)178)` to add a `'2'` superscript, according to Tahoma char tables.

`"inch of H" + AnsiString((wchar_t)8322) + "O"` should give a superscript 2, but it just gives a normal 2.

In Word, if I type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>8</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, I get a superscript 2, as expected.

Am I missing something in C++Builder?

Answer (score 3):

By converting your `wchar_t` to an `AnsiString`, you get an ANSI (8 bit) value, and hence lose all your Unicode information.

You need to just use the `String` type instead, which maps to `UnicodeString`:

```
String Text = _D("lbf/in") + String((wchar_t)178);
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau also, `L"inch of H\x2082O"` ought to work (although I couldn't comment on whether this compiler accepts it)

Comment: @M.M yes, it does

Comment: This works -- thanks! re: the _D() macro, was unable to find this in the c++builder help system (though no surprise there :-().  Also, I mistakenly called '8322' a 2 superscript. Its is subscript.

Comment: @kevinm Documentation: towards the bottom of http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/C%2B%2B_Considerations_for_Multi-Device_Applications